# Using LaTeX in HTML/JS web applications for mobile platforms

Tags: jquery, android, ios, mobile, latex

I have a question. Does anyone know a framework that allows to display LaTeX equations in web based **applicaitions** (I use jQuery Mobile) for mobile platforms (Android, iOS,..). I've tried to use MathJax but it didn't work correctly.

A problem was solved. I'm using [Equation Editor](http://www.codecogs.com/latex/htmlequations.php)

right now. But anyway, any other suggestions will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try [MathML](http://www.w3.org/Math/) an extension specifically designed to display math formulas in websites. Though as far as I know the implementation in Webkit is still lacking. You can try this page [MathML Browser Test](https://www.eyeasme.com/Joe/MathML/MathML_browser_test) for testing.